# Sitecore Custom Predicate Rule not working

Tags: list-manager, custom-field, segmented-list

I've implemented a custom Predicate to create the segmented list in Sitecore 9.1. But Segment Rule is not working.
I've followed the below steps :

1. Custom Predicate Class:
   [image: Custom Predicate class code]
2. Deployed DLL to Project Root and MA root
3. Created a condition descriptor in Sitecore
   [image: Condition Descriptor]
4. Patch File with name `sc.XConnect.CustomSegmentation.Predicates.xml` under `path_to_xconnect\App_Data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\App_Data\Config\sitecore\Segmentation`
   [image: Config]

After doing all this, when I am creating a segmented list based on the above rule, contacts are not appearing in the list.

Comment: You do not need to push the code to your MA site unless you are planning to use your code in an MA plan. But you do need to push it to your Sitecore site. Just push your dll to the sitecore site and create a segmented list using "all contacts" as the souce.

Comment: @ChrisAuer I've deleted DLL from MA plan, but still the rule is not working. I've already created a segmented list using "all contacts" as the source

Comment: In the Evaluate can you turn the return into variable. Log.Info those variables and return it. In the CreateContactSearchQuery just add a Log.Info("I'm here", this);. Let's see if you rule is running and what it says. Are you looking for a segmented list that is full of people with the 1st name of Chris?

Comment: @ChrisAuer In the CreateContactSearchQuery, I added a Log.Info("Custom Predicate", this); and getting this message in log file. Means rule is running. Yes, i am looking for a segmented list that is full of people with the matching first name. but that is not populating.

Comment: Great it is running. Let’s remove the contact.interactions.any from both functions. Just test the contact only.

Comment: @ChrisAuer Removing contact.interactions working for Evaluate method but not for CreateContactSearchQuery :(  but in log i got this exception **Failed to parse field value as JSON when validating JSON field {75AF2497-ADA0-4271-80DA-84F9DD2E4075} on item {D8DEB594-5E47-4A0B-8377-EEF8B9C24BE2}
Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException
Message: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.**       where {D8DEB594-5E47-4A0B-8377-EEF8B9C24BE2} is the ID of my segmented List

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Experience Profile and List Manager interfaces rely on personal data being available in the xDB index. As the FirstName facet is marked as [PIISensitive], you will not be able to use it by default.

To use contact facets marked [PIISensitive] in the custom predicate, please [enable indexing of PII sensitive data in the xDB index](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/enable-indexing-of-pii-sensitive-data-in-the-xdb-index.html).

I am able to see the segmented list based on FirstName after I enabled indexing of PII sensitive data in the xDB index.

Comment: Just to add more information, I tried to set the value on the following file: 
"C:\<Path to indexer>\App_data\Config\Sitecore\SearchIndexer\sc.Xdb.Collection.IndexerSettings.xml"

but it didnt work, make sure to change the value on the on-premise deployment (if you have it): 
"C:\<Path to xConnect>\root\App_data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_data\Config\Sitecore\SearchIndexer\sc.Xdb.Collection.IndexerSettings.xml"